# Finding the right terminology for "consuming code"

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the more established term for, what some people call, consuming code.

As I see it, consuming code is the part of code that is calling (consuming) APIs, libraries, utility classes etc, usually in event handlers and test cases.

And what can we call the code that the consuming code is consuming? (APIs, libraries etc) Is there a collective name for it?

Comment: caller/callee, producer/consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminus is "level": Code that relies on many APIs, libraries and other helpers is high-level, while code that doesn't is low-level.